# Scanner Wont read strings even though I used the correct .NextLine()

Tags: java

I am coding a problem for elapsed time and need some help testing to see if the user inputs am or pm. I went to use .equalsIgnoreCase(); on my string and discovered it did not store it. Here is my code

```
public static void elapsedTime()
{
    Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.print("Enter the beginning hour: ");
    int startingHour = reader.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter the beginning minute(s): ");
    int startingMinutes = reader.nextInt();
    reader.nextLine();

    System.out.print("Enter AM/PM: ");
    String startingAmOrPm = reader.nextLine();


    System.out.print("Enter the ending hour: ");
    int endingHour = reader.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter the ending minute(s): ");
    int endingMinutes = reader.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter AM/PM:  ");
    String endingAmOrPm = reader.nextLine();
    reader.nextLine();



    System.out.println("");
}
```

As I researched I discovered the reader.NextLine() but that didnt help the string not having a value. Can anybody help? Id appreciate it!

Comment: Watch where you put that first `nextLine` after a `nextInt`.

Comment: how is this a duplicate? Im sorry im new here

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstood. What is the problem, _exactly_? What do you mean by _but that didnt help the string not having a value_?

Comment: I had the issue of it not wanting to print the "Enter AM/PM" so I looked up how to get it to do so. That was when i discovered reader.NexLine() on this site. I didnt know it wouldnt cause the users input to not be stored in a string

Comment: Yeah, read the duplicate. Notice how you use `nextLine` after getting `startingMinutes` and notice how you use it after `endingMinutes`.